# Anaconda does not recognize: xgboost, catboost and lightgbm

Tags: python, package, anaconda, spyder

So I have already installed all these packages.

But I cannot import them. Anaconda gives me the error: "No module named..."

```
  # conda install -c conda-forge xgboost
  import xgboost 
  # conda install -c conda-forge catboost
  import catboost 
  # conda install -c conda-forge lightgbm
  import lightgbm as lgb
```

I have looked all over the internet, no solutions work. I cannot import the packages.

Comment: Are you in the right environment? Try > conda env list. Does > conda list  show that the packages are installed?

Answer (score 0):

Try create its own environment:

```
conda create -n boost python=3.6
```

Then activate it and install your packages there:

```
conda activate boost
conda install -c conda-forge spyder xgboost catboost lightgbm
```

In the environment type:
    spyder

And happy coding

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) To solve this problem you need to:

1. Create a conda env to install all packages that come from conda-forge. That's because conda-forge packages are binary incompatible with the default packages provided by Anaconda.
2. Read [our guide](http://docs.spyder-ide.org/ipythonconsole.html#connect-to-an-external-kernel) to understand how to connect Spyder to different Python environments.